# Как освободить инициатора события?

Tags: java, события

уважаемое сообщество!

У меня вопрос касаемый custom events в java. В моей программе есть слушатель udp сообщений, который реализован следующим образом:

```
public void run() {
    DatagramPacket receivedPacket;
    byte[] receivedData = new byte[1024];

    try {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        while(true)
        {
            Arrays.fill(receivedData, (byte)0);
            receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(receivedData, receivedData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivedPacket);
            for (udpMessageCollector mc:udpMessageCollectors
                 ) {
                mc.udpMessageReceived(receivedPacket);
            }

        }
    }catch (Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.toString());};

}
```

Как вы можете заметить этот класс реализует Runnable интерфейс и посредством события передает данные дальше программе. Обработка занимает определенное время, тем более что идет взаимодействие с БД.

Таким образом программа возвращается к слушателю UDP через определенное время. Как я могу быть уверен, что ни один отправленный мне пакет не был отброшен? Представьте себе допустим, что обработка запроса занимает секунду, а в течении этого времени будет получено 10 запросов... Я знаю, что есть буфер, который поможет принять пакеты и передаст их слушателю по возвращению, но я не знаю на сколько он большой и где он настраивается. Лучшим решением было бы освободить этот класс сразу после передачи полученных данных. Возможно ли так сделать? И вообще, как бы вы реализовали такую задачу?

Comment: А что если сначало сделать слушателя, а уже из него(при получении данных) запускать Runnable? Сразу отпадет указанная проблема

Comment: Ну это как бы противоречит логике ООП... Это все равно как сначала включать красный на светофоре, а потом создавать машину и давить на тормоз... Кроме того, там же целая программа с кучей всего. Никакой памяти не хватит, если создавать по экземпляру на каждый запрос...

Comment: Я вам написал как это делается у людей, чтобы хватило памяти - ставите ограничение и следите за ним, например если уже запущен Поток(1, 2, 10....) - не запускаем новый а клиенту отправляем ответ - "Занято, попробуй позже".... =).

Comment: Хотя... Нужно ещё раз подумать над program flow. Спасибо за подсказку! Мне такая простая мысль в голову не приходила :))

Comment: Да да. Ок я уже понял. Спасибо ещё раз!!